# Adding User Records vb.net 2010 Database(MSaccess) using Microsoft JET OLEDB 4.0

Tags: database, vb.net, oledb, oledbconnection

Hello I'm having problem saving record in my database ,When I debug the program it says "OLEDB Execption was  unhandled, Syntax Error in update statement"
Can you Help me?

Is this The right Code?

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form2
    Dim contr As String = "Provider= Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source= C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Users.mdb;"

    Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection(contr)
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Usertable SET Username = @Username, Password = @Password WHERE id = @id", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", TextBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox2.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Label3.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        con.Close()

    End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Please don't store passwords in plain text. Learn how to do password hashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password is a [reserved keyword](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266) for MS-Access. Use it enclosed in square brakets

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE Usertable SET Username = @Username, " & _ 
                            "[Password] = @Password WHERE id = @id", con)
```

Answer (score 0):

Access/OLE doesn't like named parameters. You need to use `?` placeholders:

```
UPDATE Usertable SET Username = ?, Password = ? WHERE id = ?
```

Then to match each parameter value with the placeholder, you must add them to the Parameters collection in the order the placeholder is used in the query, rather than by name.

Comment: Sorry but it is not completely true. Access accepts the placeholders like the one used in the question (probably for easy porting), The important thing is the add order in the Parameters collection, but this is already correct.